# Solving a polynomial constraint in $\Bbb F_q[x]$.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Supposing we know $f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x),f_4(x),f_5(x),f_6(x),f_7(x)\in\Bbb F_q[x]$ in $$f_7(x)=f_1(x)(\alpha f_2(x)+f_3(x))+f_4(x)(\beta f_5(x)+f_6(x))$$
where $\alpha(x),\beta(x)\in\Bbb F_q$ are unknown but of degree at most $k$ (a constant). Then can there be more than one pair of $\alpha(x),\beta(x)\in\Bbb F_q$ which satisfy $f_7(x)$ (note $\mathsf{deg}(f_3(x))\leq\mathsf{deg}(f_2(x))$ and $\mathsf{deg}(f_6(x))\leq\mathsf{deg}(f_5(x))$ may be assumed if needed)?

How to find at least one pair without trialing all possible values of $\Bbb F_q$ in preferrably $O((\log q)^c)$ steps for some $c>0$?

Assuming a solution exists is it as simple as choose an arbitrary polynomial $\alpha(x)$ and find $\beta(x)$? And so are there are always $q^{k+1}$ solutions even if one exists?

Comment: why delete solution? ok.

Comment: You didn't give me a chance to respond to your comment on those other problems you posted, as you deleted them, so I'll write here what I would have written there. It may be that your MO and m.se problems weren't the same, but they were certainly sufficiently closely related that you ought to have linked each to the other.